# The error `parse error: unexpected \"[\""` when trying to curl a metric value from Prometheus

Tags: curl, prometheus

My goal is to obtain a metric value from Prometheus via cURL inside a bash script. No browser, no Grafana dashboard. I run that command

```bash
URL="https://192.168.0.11:9090"

curl -g "$URL/api/v1/series?" \
  --data-urlencode 'match[]=kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="obfuscated",topic="output_obfuscated",partition="2"}'
```

and successfully get the metric parameters.

```json
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "__name__": "kafka_consumergroup_lag",
      "consumergroup": "obfuscated",
      "instance": "192.168.0.11:9308",
      "job": "kafka-exporter",
      "partition": "2",
      "topic": "output_obfuscated"
    }
  ]
}
```

But if I try to get the metric value for 1 minute (or 5 minutes) I'll get the error.

The command

```bash
curl -g "$URL/api/v1/series?" \
  --data-urlencode 'match[]=kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="obfuscated",topic="output_obfuscated",partition="2"}[1m]'
```

The error

```bash
{
  "status": "error",
  "errorType": "bad_data",
  "error": "invalid parameter \"match[]\": 1:109: parse error: unexpected \"[\""
}
```

In Grafana web-interface it works normally. As far as I understand, I couldn't watch the metric value by adding `[]` in the end of the code. Is there any method to get the Prometheus metric value?

Comment: [`/api/v1/series`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#finding-series-by-label-matchers) is only for fetching **series**, and `match[]` only accepts series selector. For arbitrary queries use `/api/v1/query` or `/api/v1/query_range` instead.

Comment: @markalex, you are absolutely right. But if I run ```curl -g "$URL/api/v1/query?query=kafka_consumergroup_lag" \
 --data-urlencode 'sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup=~"obfuscated",topic=~"output_obfuscated"}[1m])'``` it returns the hole `kafka_consumergroup_lag` metric.

Comment: `sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag{...}[1m])` is not a valid query. `sum` accepts instant vectors, but you are supplying it with range vector.